# Separate AJAX Forms on Single Django View

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I'm not using Django's built in forms to display the form:

Inside `view.html` is:

```
<div>
    <form id="note-form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="noteForm" />
        <textarea id="note-body" class="uk-textarea" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small uk-margin-small-top">Add Note</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Inside `veiw.py` is:

```
if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
    note_body = request.POST.get('note_body')

    response_data.update(note_author = request.user.first_name + ' ' + request.user.last_name)
    response_data.update(note_time = datetime.now().strftime('%B %m, %Y at %I:%M %p'))
    response_data['note_body'] = note_body

    Note.objects.create(item_id = id, body = note_body, author = request.user)
    return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Inside `view.js` is:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#note-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            note_body: $('#note-body').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            action: 'post'
        },
        success: function(json) {
            document.getElementById("note-form").reset();
            $('#notes').prepend(
                '<div>' +
                    json.note_body +
                    '<div class="uk-text-meta">Created by ' + json.note_author + ' on ' + json.note_time + '</div>' +
                '</div>'
            )
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

This works, and it works like a well-oiled dream, until I attempt to add another form to the page. I need a way, using this existing code (or as much as it as possible), to separate the POSTs and I can't figure it out.

I've attempted to change my `view.py` to incorporate a hidden field:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('form_name') == 'noteForm':
        ...
```

This breaks the `view.js` code, however; I attempted to change the `action: 'post'` to `action: 'noteForm'` match, but that doesn't work either -- the view doesn't get the returned JSON data and the DOM updates everything as "undefined", and then nothing gets saved to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use a single view to process two kinds of requests with two response types. It make sense to use two different views.

One view returns the HTML with both forms. The other handles your AJAX request and response.

You can point your AJAX request a different endpoint with the `url` property in the `$.ajax` settings object.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/path_to_ajax_endpoint/',
    type: 'POST',
    // The rest of your settings.
});
```